Equivalence of definition of weak solution for scalar transport equation
It may be a stupid question but I am stuck at it. I am reading a book about the control theory: consider the scalar transport equation defined on $(t,x) \in [0,T]\times [0,L]$ with $T,L>0$ given:
$$
\begin{cases}
y_t+y_x=0,\\
y(t,0)=u(t),\\
y(0,x)=y_0(x),
\end{cases} \quad \quad (1) 
$$
The author gave two definitions of the weak solution of the above system $(1)$ and said the two definition are equivalent
Definition 1: Given $u(t) \in L^2(0,T),y_0 \in L^2(0,L)$, a function $y \in C^0([0,T];L^2(0,L))$ is called a weak solution of $(1)$, if the following relation
$$
-\int_0^\tau \int_0^L (\varphi_t+\varphi_x)y \ dxdt-\int_0^\tau u(t)\varphi(t,0)dt+\int_0^Ly(\tau,x)\varphi(\tau,x)dx-\int_0^Ly_0(x)\varphi(0,x)dx=0
\quad \quad (2)
$$
holds for $\forall \tau \in [0,T]$ and $\forall \varphi(t,x) \in C^1([0,\tau]\times [0,L])$ sastifying $\varphi(t,L)\equiv 0, \forall t \in [0,\tau].$
Definition 2:  Given $T,L>0$, $u(t) \in L^2(0,T),y_0 \in L^2(0,L)$, a function $y \in C^0([0,T];L^2(0,L))$ is called a weak solution of $(1)$, if the following relation
$$
-\int_0^T \int_0^L (\varphi_t+\varphi_x)y \ dxdt-\int_0^T u(t)\varphi(t,0)dt-\int_0^Ly_0(x)\varphi(0,x)dx=0
$$
holds for $\forall \varphi(t,x) \in C^1([0,T]\times [0,L])$ sastifying $\varphi(t,L)\equiv 0, \forall t \in [0,\tau]$ and $\varphi(T,x)\equiv 0, \forall x \in [0,L].$
It is clear definition 1 implies definition 2. But I don't know how to show that definition 2 implies definition 1. Can anyone help me?
